# Reserving/locking pins between processes

Tags: gpiozero

Relatively new to RPi coding and `gpiozero` in particular.  Pardon ignorance, please.  The pin factory stuff is good for 'reserving' pins within a specific process, but is there a builtin mechanism, or supported workaround, for reserving them Pi-wide?  I expected that starting up another process that tried to use the same pins as an existing process would be blocked, but the result was.. not that.

Is there a preferred/supported mechanism for using IPC locks or mutices/semaphores to *truly* reserve GPIO pins Pi-wide?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way of reserving GPIO Pi wide.

A lot of the existing Pi GPIO libraries talk directly to the hardware and the last library to configure a GPIO wins.

The kernel supports claiming GPIO but this only works if other software use the same interface (and unfortunately the claim only lasts for the duration of the software process).

Comment: Thanks.  So if I'm the only user of the Pi (*i.e.*, all of the software is under my control), I'd have to write my own wrappers for this?  (Apologies for terminological confusion; I'm used to thinking of 'GPIO' as meaning the entire J8 header, not just single pins.)

Comment: Yes, you would have to mediate use of the GPIO.

Comment: Thank you! for the explanation and confirmation.